# iOS custom keyboard typing is extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, custom-keyboard

I created a custom keyboard on xcode using Swift. It works perfectly on simulator but when I tested it on real device the response was very slow (min 5 sec) though keyboard appears quickly. I do not know what is the problem. When button is pressed it takes too much time to type the text or sometimes crashes. Any ideas?

```
func handleTapOnButton(button: UIButton) {
    let buttonText = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    if let proxy = textDocumentaryProxy {
        if button.titleForState(.Normal) == " " {
            proxy.insertText(" ")
        } else {
            proxy.insertText(buttonText!)
        }
    }
    if globals.tapped != 3 && (switchedToNumbers == false) {
        lowerCase()
        globals.tapped = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: `sometimes crashes` whats the error you get? and show us your code, how can we debug it without seeing it?

Comment: there is no error but slow performance

Comment: are you using shadows?

Comment: no but I am using sound

Comment: what is the type of your UIButtons, system or custom? Use UIButton type Custom

Answer (score 0):

You can you TouchDown Event if you have used TouchUpInside. It may help.